# How do you set a notify URL for PayPal NVP recurring payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

When performing a `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` operation, it's possible to set `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL` to define the IPN endpoint for any incoming notifications from PayPal.

It's also possible to set the NOTIFYURL in the `SetExpressCheckout` operation, but doing so doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is hugely convenient; especially if you run multiple projects with the same PayPal account.

However, there does not seem to be an equivalent for `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` - unless I'm missing something.

I know the URL can be set manually, but I want to be able to set it on a per profile basis.

Is this possible? If it isn't, does any one know actually why not? Seems like an odd inconsistency if it isn't possible.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The notify URL applies only to DoExpressCheckoutPayment. This value is ignored when set in SetExpressCheckout or GetExpressCheckoutDetails.
In addition, The IPN URL can be only set in the Paypal account for recurring payments notifications.

Comment: "If it isn't, does any one know actually why not? Seems like an odd inconsistency if it isn't possible." Any insight on this point? Bear in mind your older APIs support setting a different notification URL for each transaction and ultimately this makes the user experience much better. It also enables people who operate multiple sites to be able to use the same account to receive funds from different sites to the same account. Don't want to seem over dramatic, but this is a MASSIVE oversight. I'm currently questioning why I should even move to using the NVP API.

Comment: While we're talking about oversights, I already made a conscious effort not to bother using the REST API due to broken promises regarding support for webhooks for recurring payments. I'm seriously reconsidering using PayPal at all. You guys seem to have lost your way a bit.

Comment: And, please, why on earth does the INITAMT not get taken immediately?